# Inconsident indentation with SCSS in webstorm file watcher

Tags: sass, webstorm

I am using Webstorm file watcher to transpile my .scss file in to a .css file. Whenever the process runs, it gives me an error

```
error main.css (Line 37: Inconsistent indentation: 2 spaces were used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 8 spaces.)
```

I have seen this happen to others through some google searching but none of their solutions seem to help me. And as far as I am aware, scss shouldn't complain about indentation.

Here are my file watcher settings

[image]

Comment: Are you certain you're compiling .scss files and not *.sass* files?  Because you should only be able to get that error with .sass files.

Comment: I know, that's what is confusing the hell out of me. I'm new to ruby and sass so find it harder than most to diagnose the problem. As you can see in the image, I am targeting the scss.bat so I wonder if there could be something wrong with my sass install

Comment: Have you tried compiling via command line (ie. not using Webstorm)?  If you still get the error, then the problem is located in your Sass files somewhere (if you're not using the .sass extension for anything you've written, maybe you're using a 3rd party library that does?)

Comment: Ok so command line failed to output anything but I tried installing Koala and that works perfectly on the same files

Answer (score 1):

You probably solved it by now, but I recently had the same error (same line number and everything). To help others who run into the same problem.

your 'arguments' are wrong.
you are telling the compiler to compile the .css file (to nowhere).
change it into:

--no-cache --update $fileName$:$fileNameWithoutExtension$.css